# Determining cause of MSMQ Poison Queue Exception

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, system.diagnostics, self-hosting

I have a WCF self-hosted service that listens to the poison queue.  I also turned on the service model tracking turned on:

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="D:\Logs\PoisonQueueSvcModel.svclog" />
                </listeners>
            </source>
```

In this log file, it's logging a bunch of errors:

> The transport channel detected a poison message. This occurred because
>   the message exceeded the maximum number of delivery attempts or
>   because the channel detected a fundamental problem with the message.
>   The inner exception may contain additional information.

Because WCF is logging this in the service model log, I of course can't see the inner exception.  Is there a way to determine what the specific cause of the problem is?  Is there a way to catch these kinds of errors in the application?

Comment: which Windows do you use?

Comment: It's on Windows Server 2012

Comment: use ETW to capture .Net Runtime Exception events. Copy this into a new WPRP file (http://pastebin.com/NXjDyiFH), install the WPT (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx)  and run it via WPR: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -start  DotNetRuntime.wprp && timeout -1 && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\wpr.exe" -stop Result.etl** Open the Result.etl in WPA, go to the generic events table, lad symbols and expand the stack of Exception events.

Comment: where you able to see more details when looking at the ETL file?